# Stochastic Gradient Descent for Ratio of non-linear functions

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization, sampling, non-convex-optimization

I came across a paper where the loss function to optimize is a ratio of two non-linear functions, which looks like this:

[[image: <span class=]$w$ is the parameter and \delta is an indicator variable" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yM4O.png)

Citing that the function cannot be optimized with SGD in this form, they formulate it as a constraint optimization problem as follows:

[image]

I can understand till this point, but after formulating the problem in this form, they (re)-formulate this problem as a series of unconstraint optimization problems as follows:

[image]

[image]

Where it's claimed that $S_j$ does not influence the parameter values, and the final optimization objective is:

[image]

I couldn't follow the logic. Is this a standard deduction of a fractional optimization problem? Will this formulation give sub-optimal results as compared to the original one?

***Paper Link:*** https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_etal_18a.pdf

Comment: Please transcribe the images. If Imgur is down, your question becomes incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

They give not a reformulation, but an algorithm to compute the optimal value of the original problem.

Assuming you have the optimal $S^*$, the first two problems are equivalent. But normally you don't know the value of $S^*$, so you can explore the range of these sum values $S$. So for each $S_j$ from the range the constrained optimization problem has to be solved.

The authors write the Lagrange multipliers form for the constrained optimization problem. And note that for each value of $S_j$ there will be a specific value of the Lagrange multipliers. So instead of fixing the value of $S_j$ they fix the value of the Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$ and solve the unconstrained optimization of the Lagrange function with $\lambda$ fixed. And for each value of $\lambda$ (call it $\lambda_i$) there will be a specific value of the constraining value $S_i$, so they still explore the range for $S$ by fixing different values of $\lambda$.

Then having several values of $\hat w$ (call it $\hat w_i$ for each $\lambda_i$) they select the value $i^*$ which gives the minimal $R_{\textbf{SNIPS}}(\pi_{\hat w_{i^*}})$ among all $R_{\textbf{SNIPS}}(\pi_{\hat w_{i}})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for looking at the paper. I am still confused about it. In the experiment section, it's mentioned that the value of the lagrange multiplier is tuned via Eq. 13 in the paper. It means it is considered as a hyper-param, whereas it is a param of the problem. Also, I don't see how the param value from the modified optimization routine will be the same if we were to optimize the original one?

Comment: The range of sum values is a hyperparameter, so equivalently the range of lagrange multipliers is also a hyperparameter.
Obviously if the optimal sum value is in the range and in the grid point of the range then the algoritm will give you this optimal value, otherwise not.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for answering. I was wondering if there is something principled that could be used for optimization here, instead of the proposed method. Maybe something like Fractional Programming? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming